# CNContactViewController doesn't provide Done button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontactviewcontroller

I am using the CNContactViewController to enter information for a new client.  But however I present the CNContactViewController I only get a "Cancel" button in the top bar...  There is no Done button, or any other way to dismiss the controller.

How can I enable a Done button (or any other way for the user to accept the newly-entered contact information)?

I saw this question, but didn't help with the Done button... 
[CNContactViewController does something strange with responder chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722827/cncontactviewcontroller-does-something-strange-with-responder-chain)

Thanks

Comment: In your question I can't find what you already tried yourself (code) or what error you're getting. please read How to ask stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: CNContactViewController can be used several different ways. You are not showing how _you_ are using it, so the question is meaningless.

Comment: After much trial and error I finally found that I need to get access to the device Contacts using the requestAccessForEntityType: method before trying to use the CNContactViewController.  Once I have authorization the Done button appears.  Thanks for the tips on how to ask better questions; I'll add code examples next time...

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `CNContactViewController` to add a `done` button to the `navigationItem`.

Something like this:

```
import ContactsUI

class ContactDetailsViewController: CNContactViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        updateNavigationItem()
    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        updateNavigationItem()
    }

    private func updateNavigationItem() {
        if !isEditing {
            // add a 0.5 seconds delay to add button after the editing animation finishes
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = .init(
                    barButtonSystemItem: .done,
                    target: self,
                    action: #selector(self.doneTapped)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    @objc private func doneTapped() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

In order to make use of this class, make sure that `ContactDetailsViewController` is embedded inside a `UINavigationController`.

Although I'm so late to answer, but I hope this helps you or someone else.